# "not a legal formal parameter"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have this unit test:

```
class MyServiceSpec extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with MockitoSugar
  with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  "MyService" must {
    "succeed if my-endpoint succeeds" in {
      Server.withRouter() {
        GET("/my-endpoint") => Action {
          Results.Ok.sendResource("myservice/my-endpoint.txt")
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
          val result = Await.result(
            new RealMyService(client).getFromEndpoint(), 10.seconds)
          result shouldEqual true
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

`sbt` is telling me:

```
» sbt test-only MyService
...
[error] /repos/myrepo/test/services/MyServiceSpec.scala:34: not a legal formal parameter.
[error] Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
[error]       Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
[error]       or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
[error]         GET("/my-endpoint") => Action {
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 16, 2017 7:27:11 AM
```

And IntelliJ is telling me:

```
Application does not take parameters: } expected
```

On line:

```
GET("/my-endpoint") => Action {
```

What does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.withRouter()` is expecting a pattern matching block. Something like this:

```
Server.withRouter() {
  case GET("/my-endpoint") => Action(whatever)
  case GET("/my-other-endpoint") => Action(whatever)
  case POST("/my-other-endpoint") => Action(whatever)
  case other => Action(whatever) // bad request
}
```

Pattern matching is just a partial function, so for example

```
whatever.map((i: Int) => i)
```

and

```
whatever.map { case (i: Int) => i }
```

both do the same thing. However, big difference is that the second one is able to perform the deconstruction by using the `unapply()` method, which is the whole point of pattern matching.

Back to your case - pattern matching is used to match the `GET("/my-endpoint")` case class (with case classes you get some goodies for free, such as `unapply` defined automatically for you). Without pattern matching, your block doesn't make sense; it would be a normal function where the left-hand side would need a formal parameter, such as `(i: Int) => ...` or `(s: String) => ...`. Having `GET("/my-endpoint")` simply makes no sense, it's not a formal parameter (that's what SBT is trying to tell you).

Comment: Thanks! I removed accidentally the `case` keyword, and never noticed again. Neither `sbt` nor `IntelliJ` were very helpful though.

Comment: I see your pain, but on the other hand, sbt seems pretty helpful to me. Instead of having a formal parameter, you had a statement to be evaluated. It's like saying `(1+2) => whatever` is a function. But anyways, glad you sorted it out. :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, `sbt` is on point, but my mind was stubbornly refusing the acknowledge the `case` keyword in the hint from `sbt`! Looking at it now seems pretty obvious ... I should take a course "how to read error messages without missing important bits and pieces"